# Ubuntu: remotely disable upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I have a number of Ubuntu machines that have `unattended-upgrades` set up. I am running 11.10 and do not wish to update to 12.04. How can I disable the upgrade dialog (which still pops up after booting the machines) from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`,

```
> # default behavior for the release upgrader
> #
> 
> [DEFAULT]
> # default prompting behavior, valid options:
> #  never  - never prompt for a new distribution version
> #  normal - prompt if a new version of the distribution is available
> #  lts    - prompt only if a LTS version of the distribution is available Prompt=normal
> Prompt=never
```

You probably want to set it to never.

Comment: am i the only one who thinks that is incredibly unclear?  "never prompt" sounds like it'll never ask if you want to update or not.

Comment: Well in my case, this is the desired behavior

Answer (score 1):

I find this gives better granularity

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
```

Set all Options to 0 to disable auto updates, but you can adjust as you wish:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```